# Per file compiler flags in Xcode 8.1

Tags: xcode

I need to add some specific compiler flags only for certain files in my project. I did some googling and found out that this used to be possible in the file inspector in older Xcode versions. I'm on Xcode 8.1, however, and I can't seem to find where I can add custom compiler flags for certain files.

Could anybody please tell me how this is possible with Xcode 8.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to the navigation bar of your project
2. Click on your project
3. Click on the target you want to modify
4. Click on Build Phases
5. Look for the file you want to add the compiler flag in the Compile Sources list; in this list you should see two columns: name and **compiler flags**
6. Click on the latter column and a popup window should come up; add the compiler flags to that specific file